# Why does var = (dct[range(x, y)] == 'str') not work?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, variables, range

I thought that the upcoming code, the variable between 1 and 144 ( in a dictionary ) with the string title 'py' minus 1 would result in a variable 1 before the variable with the string title 'py'

```
if (movement.lower == 'left'):
    a = ((one_to_[range(1, 144)] == 'py') - int(1))
    print(a)
```

Example : 32 == 'py' - 1 = 31
121 == 'py' - 1 = 120
and so on ...

Comment: Dictionaries don't work like that. Dictionaries are *maps* from keys to values. `range(1, 44)` is a perfectly valid key, it doesn't represent many keys. Although you could design an API that way it would be confusing.

Comment: would it work if i give every integer a variable ?

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga I will change know my whole script and use the dictionaries right. thanks for helping a new python programmer ;-).